# Any OSX tool to batch remove (or convert) embedded album artwork in MP3 files?

Tags: itunes, file-conversion, mp3, id3-tag, album-art

my car audio system does not support MP3 album artworks embedded in PNG format.. unfortunately iTunes switched to this format a while ago.

I'd need to find a way to remove (or convert to JPG) all artwork data in PNG from a big set of files and directories.

Is there any tool that can do that in batch?

I've seen some CLI tools like [EyeD3](http://eyed3.nicfit.net/) or [id3v2](http://id3v2.sourceforge.net/) but seems they require some compilation steps or Python install... too complicated for me...

I'm using some of [Dougscripts](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/scripts13.php) plugins for copying files to the SD card, but there's no tool working on PNG album artwork.

Thanks!!.
L.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `id3v2` to remove all artwork from your mp3 files. I appreciate your wanting to avoid compiling and the like, so below is an easier way to get the tool onto your Mac.

## Remove all artwork with `id3v2`

The following command will iterate over mp3 files found in the current folder and remove any embedded artwork:

```
id3v2 -r "APIC" *.mp3
```

The following command will iterate over mp3 files found in one layer of folders deep:

```
id3v2 -r "APIC" */*.mp3
```

### `homebrew` – how to get `id3v2` onto your Mac

To install id3v2 on your Mac, without needing to delve too deeply into compiling and other developer concerns, use [`homebrew`](https://brew.sh).

Follow the instructions on the homebrew link to get started. Once `homebrew` is available on your Mac, you can install `id3v2` using the command:

```
brew install id3v2
```

To remove `id3v2` from your Mac use:

```
brew remove id3v2
```

## Other Approaches

There are other tools that can manipulate mp3 tags and artwork. Most are available through the `homebrew` project and thus you can quickly try them out.

See [Re-encode uploaded/submitted MP3's with LAME removing artwork but keeping ID3 tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715338) for other approaches using `lame` or more general tools in [command line tool to edit mp3 ID3 tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234099).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Tagger](http://bilalh.github.io/projects/tagger/) can do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with a command line tool, ffmpeg can convert one file at a time. However, for the batch processing, some shell programming will be required. Disclaimer: ffmpeg asks before overwriting, but before processing your mp3 collection with a self written bash script, better backup your data. 
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191270/how-can-i-convert-id3v2-embedded-pngs-to-jpgs) post on stackoverflow is related.

You pass the input file to ffmpeg with the -i option, specify the codecs for video ('none' or 'mjpeg' in this case) and audio ('copy' in this case)

Converting:

```
ffmpeg -i song_with_any_artwork.mp3 -c:v mjpeg -c:a copy song_with_mjpeg_artwork.mp3
```

Removing:

```
ffmpeg -i song_with_artwork.mp3 -vn -c:a copy song_only.mp3
```